# How to use FFmpeg to live HLS stream with subtitle?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, subtitle, live-video

I want to use FFmpeg to live HLS stream with subtitle.
I have a Media. The Media have one video track, two audio track, four subtitle.
But, I tryed this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mkv \
-map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 -strict -2 -s 426x240   -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename video/videoTrack240p_%d.ts      video/videoTrack240p.m3u8 \
-map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 -strict -2 -s 1280x720  -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename video/videoTrack720p_%d.ts      video/videoTrack720p.m3u8 \
-map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 -strict -2 -s 1920x1080 -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename video/videoTrack1080p_%d.ts     video/videoTrack1080p.m3u8 \
-map 0:a:0 -c:a aac                             -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename audio/audioTrack1_%d.aac        audio/audioTrack0.m3u8 \
-map 0:a:1 -c:a aac                             -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename audio/audioTrack0_%d.aac        audio/audioTrack1.m3u8 \
-map 0:s:0 -c:s webvtt                          -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename subtitle/subtitleTrack0_%d.vtt  subtitle/subtitleTrack0.m3u8 \
-map 0:s:1 -c:s webvtt                          -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename subtitle/subtitleTrack1_%d.vtt  subtitle/subtitleTrack1.m3u8 \
-map 0:s:2 -c:s webvtt                          -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename subtitle/subtitleTrack2_%d.vtt  subtitle/subtitleTrack2.m3u8 \
-map 0:s:3 -c:s webvtt                          -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename subtitle/subtitleTrack3_%d.vtt  subtitle/subtitleTrack3.m3u8
```

It show this Error:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[matroska,webm @ 0x5631128c1460] Could not find codec parameters for stream 5 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[matroska,webm @ 0x5631128c1460] Could not find codec parameters for stream 6 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input0.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : GRAVITY DAZE The Animation Ouverture
    encoder         : libebml v1.2.3 + libmatroska v1.3.0
    creation_time   : 2017-03-30T06:22:52.000000Z
  Duration: 00:17:23.58, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2155 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Stream #0:2(jpn): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:3(chi): Subtitle: ass (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : CHT
    Stream #0:4(chi): Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      title           : CHS
    Stream #0:5(jpn): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle
    Stream #0:6(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle
[hls @ 0x5631128fc840] Opening 'subtitle/subtitleTrack0_0.vtt' for writing
[hls @ 0x5631128fc840] Opening 'subtitle/subtitleTrack00.vtt' for writing
[mpegts @ 0x56311296bda0] No streams to mux were specified
Could not write header for output file #5 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #2:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #3:0 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #4:0 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:3 -> #5:0 (ass (ssa) -> webvtt (native))
  Stream #0:4 -> #6:0 (ass (ssa) -> webvtt (native))
  Stream #0:5 -> #7:0 (hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) -> webvtt (native))
  Stream #0:6 -> #8:0 (hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) -> webvtt (native))
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

If the command not add subtitle:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mkv \
-map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 -strict -2 -s 426x240   -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename video/videoTrack240p_%d.ts      video/videoTrack240p.m3u8 \
-map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 -strict -2 -s 1280x720  -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename video/videoTrack720p_%d.ts      video/videoTrack720p.m3u8 \
-map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 -strict -2 -s 1920x1080 -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename video/videoTrack1080p_%d.ts     video/videoTrack1080p.m3u8 \
-map 0:a:0 -c:a aac                             -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename audio/audioTrack1_%d.aac        audio/audioTrack0.m3u8 \
-map 0:a:1 -c:a aac                             -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename audio/audioTrack0_%d.aac        audio/audioTrack1.m3u8
```

The streaming is work without error.
I cannot find FFmpeg streaming with subtitle example on long time.

Answer (score 0):

To create segmented subtitles and their corresponding HLS playlist file, you need to use the more generic `segment` output format instead of `hls`.

Here's an example that creates segmented `VTT` subtitles with `0000.vtt` filename format and a playlist named `chunklist_vtt.m3u8`.
Please note that FFmpeg automatically determines the internal format of the playlist by analyzing the file extension of the `-segment_list`, but this can be set with the `segment_format` option.

**Command breakdown:**

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i input.mp4 \
-vn \                               # drop all video streams
-an \                               # drop all audio streams
-map s:0 \                          # select the first embedded subtitle stream
-f segment \                        # use generic segment format
-segment_time 3.0 \                 # set segment duration
-segment_list chunklist_vtt.m3u8 \  # set playlist filename (internal format determined by extension)
%04d.vtt                            # output filename (internal format determined by extension)
```

**Output files:**

By printing the contents of a subtitle segment, you can see that these contain only fragments of the original subtitle:

```
$ cat 0000.vtt
WEBVTT

00:00.000 --> 00:02.880
you may have seen videos in which someone is using  

00:02.880 --> 00:06.660
an old computer when it suddenly 
makes popping and crackling noises
```

And also the playlist has the default HLS format:

```
$ head -n9 chunklist_vtt.m3u8
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXTINF:6.660000,
0000.vtt
#EXTINF:6.120000,
0001.vtt
```

For more detailed explanation, please check the related documentation here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment

I hope this is what you were looking for.